# PySpark: I think my GroupBy is applying the function on the entire column instead of unique subgroups

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe with columns 'asin' and 'price'. Here are the first 20 rows:

```
+----------+-----+
|asin      |price|
+----------+-----+
|B006I74FRS|27.99|
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|41.95|
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|24.99|
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|58.0 |
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|5.49 |
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|30.0 |
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|15.99|
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|null |
|B006I74FRS|3.99 |
|B006I74FRS|19.99|
|B006I74FRS|9.55 |
+----------+-----+
```

What I am trying to do is for every product ID (under the column called 'asin'), find the count of rows/prices that are associated with that product ID. So I did

```
df.groupby('asin').count()
```

but then the output came out as

```
+----------+-------+
|asin      |count  |
+----------+-------+
|B007ATO2Z8|1000000|
|B005BFKR2A|1000000|
|B006I74FRS|1000000|
|B00FQITYO4|1000000|
|B00B105J0E|1000000|
|B00F9RNZ24|1000000|
|B006IIZOZO|1000000|
|B007ECGY02|1000000|
|B00GMRMCBA|1000000|
+----------+-------+
```

I think the groupby is being applied to the entire price columns as opposed to on each unique asin subgroup. How can I tackle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's doing the right thing, but it's not dropping the NULLs. Try below where I only count the non-null entries:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupBy('asin').agg(F.sum(F.col('count').isNotNull().cast('int')))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by nulls? Are you saying that the 1000000 values are null values? Regardless, I wish to keep null values in my result computation.

Comment: the 1000000 values include null values. If you want to keep them, then your code is actually right. what makes you think that `the groupby is being applied to the entire price columns as opposed to on each unique asin subgroup`?

Comment: I am thinking that because when I do .summary().collect() on the resulting dataframe, the mean is 1000000 and the standard deviation is 0.

Comment: That's because all the groups contain the same number of rows (1000000). Is that unexpected?

Comment: Also, when I do collect_list() instead of count during the groupby, every row ends up looking the same - a very very long list.

Comment: What's the problem with that? What is your expected outcome, and what is unexpected in the actual outcome?